# Code inside for in loop not being executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I have the following method, I've verified that the for in loop runs, however the code inside it doesn't. I really can't explain myself this behaviour.

```
- (void) getReviews:(NSString *)packageID withCompletionHandler:(ResponseBlock)completionBlock {
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"packageID" : packageID};
    [manager GET:(@"theurl") parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSTEasyJSON* JSON = [NSTEasyJSON withObject:responseObject];
        NSString *jsonString = JSON.string;
        if ([jsonString containsString:@"Could"]) {
            completionBlock(jsonString);
        } else {
            for (NSTEasyJSON *arrayItemJSON in JSON.dictionary) {
                NSString* rte = arrayItemJSON[@"rate"].string;
                NSString* ttl = arrayItemJSON[@"title"].string;
                NSString* rvw = arrayItemJSON[@"review"].string;
                NSString* uname = arrayItemJSON[@"username"].string;

                NSLog(@"This is the rate %@", rte);
            }
        }
        completionBlock(jsonString);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        completionBlock(@"Error ocurred");
    }];

}
```

Comment: Does the response contain what you expect?

Comment: @bbum It does, and I've as well verified the the for loop runs as many times as it should according to the number of elements in the JSON Array.

Comment: Just before the `for` add `NSLog(@"count: %d", JSON.dictionary.count);`. What do you get?

Comment: @rmaddy count: 2

Comment: What is the actual data type of `JSON.dictionary`? The loop kind of implies it is an `NSArray` but the name implies it is an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @rmaddy It is `NSArray`

Comment: So you are saying that a breakpoint on the `NSString *rte = ...` line is not being hit despite there being two objects in the array?

Comment: @rmaddy That's correct, I really can't explain why.

Comment: Is the code in your question an **exact** copy and paste from your real code or did you tweak it a bit for the question?

Comment: @rmaddy Exact copy paste except for the URL value.

Comment: Can you try `([jsonString containsString:@"Could"]) {
            //completionBlock(jsonString);
        }` and see if it works.